# Minimum number of edges formula?

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a formula of finding the minimum number of edges?

I know that for the maximum number of edges it is

$(n-k)(n-k+1)/2$ where $n$ is the number of vertices and $k$ is number of components.

I was reading online and some said $(n-1)(n-2)/2 +1$
however in my case I know there are $n=10$ vertices and $k=3$ components, hence the max number of edges is $28$.

If I apply the formula for min. found online I get $37$ edges which is clearly wrong.

Comment: Clarify? A graph can have no edges... What are n and k?

Comment: The minimum number of edges is $0$. If you know some other things about the graphs under consideration, they need to be included.

Comment: @GregMartin is a graph with zero edges considered simple graph? In my case I have 10vertices and 3 components is it correct to draw 5 vertices in one component, 3 vertices in the second component and 2 vertices in the third component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a single component with $m$ vertices, you need $m-1$ edges. In your case, you need to have three components with $a,b,c$ vertices respectively, with $a+b+c=10$. It doesn't matter what you choose for $a,b,c$, in any case you need $$(a-1) + (b-1) + (c-1) = 10-3=7$$ edges to make such a graph.

So in general the formula is just $n-k$.